# Sliding a Tab Left, Pause then Slide back to the Right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to jQuery and to be honset, I'm unsure if this is even the right way to even go about writing the script! I've been looking over scripts here, and on the web, and pieced this together. Anyway, I'm trying to get my image to the following...

1. Slide out to the Left.
2. Pause (Delay?) for 3 seconds.
3. Slide back to the Right.
4. Completes animation, before you can hover over it again.

I made a Fiddle to help explain better.
http://jsfiddle.net/brandonesc/wvezk/179/

Right now, if you hover over the tab multiple times, fast, it has this "Jittery?" effect to it, which I'm unsure of how that's even caused.

Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it. I've been stumped on this for the last 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

This one is actually pretty complicated.

http://jsfiddle.net/wvezk/180/

You need to leverage callbacks to get the order of operations you want. I also made use of the `data` attribute to keep track of when events should be fired/not fired. I also had to change your CSS and switch it to `animate` from `show`. Show works by wrapping the element in a container. This caused the popping effect.

```
$('#slider').mouseover(function() {
    //if we are animating then punt
    if ($(this).data('animating') == true) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).data('animating', true);

    //animate the move
    $(this).animate({
        left: '-25px'
    }, 500, function() {
        //in callback return to original state
        setTimeout(function() {
            animationCallback();
        }, 1000);
    });
});

function animationCallback() {
    //move back
    $('#slider').animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 500, function() {
        //in callback trun off animation
        $(this).data('animating', false);
    });
}​
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, your example works great, except I have a few questions. I know you had to change my css, but it seems with the "left:0;" you added it now shoots the "slider" flush with the browser, like it's glued.

Here's more of what I'm trying to accomplish looks like, with some code from my site. I'm sorry, I thought this was going to be straight forward, so I simplified, of what I was going for in the first fiddle. Please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/brandonesc/NRD4Q/42/ I have a few divs, that are hiding the "slider" to give it a hidden look.

Comment: notice, how if you resize the "result" section, the "slider" is glued, and follows the resize. The slider, by default will be showing about 30px the rest will be hidden behind the green div. And of course, when hovered it shows, and goes back to showing "30px" can this be accomplished without it sticking to the browser, when resized? My HTML and CSS may be effecting your script?

Comment: @Brandon - I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish. From your updated example my initial impression is that you are doing this all wrong. You might want to post another SO question with more detail of what you are doing and why. I don't have time to troubleshoot for you.